# What is Cache in Sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, testing

I heared  Output Caching  is the one of the performance tuning technique in sharepoint....what is output caching , Compression in sharepoint....Let me know what are the performance tuning techniques in sharepoint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance tuning in SharePoint is a big topic with a lot of independent knobs that you can turn.  There is quite a bit of art to go along with the science.  Sean McDonough put together a pretty comprehensive overview of the areas that you have control over:

http://sharepointinterface.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/caching-in-for-sharepoint-performance.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Output cache is feature of ASP.NET and not sharepoint. There is a setting in SharePoint to enable it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx

You are probably talking about IIS compression as well which is another performance tuning technique at IIS leve:

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/02/22/iis-7-compression-good-bad-how-much.aspx

These are two very good articles on caching in sharepoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661294.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647588.aspx